# if i have an jsonarray and i display it in listview and want a specifec item from the list how to do it?

Tags: android, json, listview

what im trying to do is look at the json pull all the names to a list view(save the imdbid of that names) and from there you can click on a movie and it will go to a new intent that will bring you the movie that you clicked on with its name summary and an image

im searching in a json with an array in it that looks like this(it based on what the user searched so this is one example...)

```
  {"Search":[{"Title":"Batman     Begins","Year":"2005","imdbID":"tt0372784","Type":"movie","Poster":"http://ia.media-imdb.com/images/M/MV5BNTM3OTc0MzM2OV5BMl5BanBnXkFtZTYwNzUwMTI3._V1_SX300.jpg"},{"Title":"Batman v Superman: Dawn of Justice","Year":"2016","imdbID":"tt2975590","Type":"movie","Poster":"http://ia.media-imdb.com/images/M/MV5BNTE5NzU3MTYzOF5BMl5BanBnXkFtZTgwNTM5NjQxODE@._V1_SX300.jpg"},{"Title":"Batman","Year":"1989","imdbID":"tt0096895","Type":"movie","Poster":"http://ia.media-imdb.com/images/M/MV5BMTYwNjAyODIyMF5BMl5BanBnXkFtZTYwNDMwMDk2._V1_SX300.jpg"},{"Title":"Batman Returns","Year":"1992","imdbID":"tt0103776","Type":"movie","Poster":"http://ia.media-imdb.com/images/M/MV5BODM2OTc0Njg2OF5BMl5BanBnXkFtZTgwMDA4NjQxMTE@._V1_SX300.jpg"},{"Title":"Batman Forever","Year":"1995","imdbID":"tt0112462","Type":"movie","Poster":"http://ia.media-imdb.com/images/M/MV5BNWY3M2I0YzItNzA1ZS00MzE3LThlYTEtMTg2YjNiOTYzODQ1XkEyXkFqcGdeQXVyMTQxNzMzNDI@._V1_SX300.jpg"},{"Title":"Batman & Robin","Year":"1997","imdbID":"tt0118688","Type":"movie","Poster":"http://ia.media-imdb.com/images/M/MV5BNTM1NTIyNjkwM15BMl5BanBnXkFtZTcwODkxOTQxMQ@@._V1_SX300.jpg"},{"Title":"Batman: The Animated Series","Year":"1992–1995","imdbID":"tt0103359","Type":"series","Poster":"http://ia.media-imdb.com/images/M/MV5BMTU3MjcwNzY3NF5BMl5BanBnXkFtZTYwNzA2MTI5._V1_SX300.jpg"},{"Title":"Batman: Under the Red Hood","Year":"2010","imdbID":"tt1569923","Type":"movie","Poster":"http://ia.media-imdb.com/images/M/MV5BMTMwNDEyMjExOF5BMl5BanBnXkFtZTcwMzU4MDU0Mw@@._V1_SX300.jpg"},{"Title":"Batman: The Dark Knight Returns, Part 1","Year":"2012","imdbID":"tt2313197","Type":"movie","Poster":"http://ia.media-imdb.com/images/M/MV5BMzIxMDkxNDM2M15BMl5BanBnXkFtZTcwMDA5ODY1OQ@@._V1_SX300.jpg"},{"Title":"Batman: Mask of the Phantasm","Year":"1993","imdbID":"tt0106364","Type":"movie","Poster":"http://ia.media-imdb.com/images/M/MV5BMTMzODU0NTYxN15BMl5BanBnXkFtZTcwNDUxNzUyMQ@@._V1_SX300.jpg"}],"totalResults":"310","Response":"True"}
```

so what i want to do is get the imdbid when he clicks on the listview which contains the movie name
this is what i tried:

```
   JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(finalJson);
            JSONArray parentArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("Search");
            StringBuffer finalStringBuffer = new StringBuffer();
            String imdbid ;
            for (int i=0; i<parentArray.length(); i++){
                JSONObject finalJsonObject = parentArray.getJSONObject(i);
                String movieName = finalJsonObject.getString("Title");
                nameOfMovie.add(movieName);
                String year = finalJsonObject.getString("Year");
                yearOfMovie.add(year);
                String omdbID = finalJsonObject.getString("imdbID");
                id.add(omdbID);
                finalStringBuffer.append(movieName + " , " + year + " , " + omdbID + "\n");
                imdbid = omdbID ;
            }

        }
        catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
```

but how can i know the imdbid(which is in the movie name that is displayed in a list) that he cliked on?
listview code:

```
 listViewInternetScreen.setClickable(true);
    listViewInternetScreen.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int position, long i) {
            Intent intenttoEditScreen=new Intent(AddFromInternet.this, EditMovie.class);
            setResult(RESULT_OK,intenttoEditScreen);
            String jsonMovieName = String.valueOf(nameOfMovie);
            String jsonMovieSummery = String.valueOf(yearOfMovie);
            String jsonImageURL = String.valueOf(id);

            intenttoEditScreen.putExtra("json", jsonMovieName);
            intenttoEditScreen.putExtra("json", jsonMovieSummery);
            intenttoEditScreen.putExtra("json", jsonImageURL);
            startActivity(intenttoEditScreen);


        }

        });
```

and the search method:

```
     btnGo = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnGo);
    assert btnGo != null;
    btnGo.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {


            //MAKE A SEARCH STRING AND PARSE THE RESULT
            final String search = "http://www.omdbapi.com/?s=" + EtSearch.getText().toString();
            Log.e("JSON", search);
            new JSONParser().execute(search);
            ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<>(nameOfMovie);
            arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(AddFromInternet.this,
                    android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, list);
            arrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            listViewInternetScreen.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
            Log.e("JSON MOVIE", String.valueOf(nameOfMovie));

        }
    });
```

thanks for any help :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Step 1: Use Gson (and Retrofit, if you'd like) to simplify turning a JSON string into a list of Java objects

Step 2: Make a custom ArrayAdapter that loads this list of objects. Then, when you add an Item click listener, you can get that object from the list item you clicked, and start the Intent for showing the full info for that movie.

Additional step would be to make the Movie object Parcelable, so you can add the object to the Intent in one line, rather than each individual field it contains

Comment: thanks will try when ill be home 
but just a quick qustion about the gson, if i use it i wont need the: JSONObject finalJsonObject = parentArray.getJSONObject(i);
but just the gson method to put in string and its array types?

Comment: Once you toss your JSON to the following link, and check the options for Gson and such, then you use Gson to generate Java objects, and you'll have an Arraylist instead of that line. You no longer need to manually parse out a JSON array.  The Gson documentation has plenty of useful examples. http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org

Comment: A retrofit example can be seen here.  https://github.com/santhoshvai/omdb-android-client